# jQuery: on() is now preferred over live(), but on() doesn't work with jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I've been struggling with the following function:

```
$('#pageName').on('pagebeforecreate', function() {
  // Compile the page using Handlebars
});
```

Then I tried switching `on` to `live`, despite the jQuery documentation saying that `live` is deprecated. Now everything works fine. What gives?

Comment: Is `#pageName` created dynamically after the page is loaded?

Comment: Yes, `#pageName` is a `data-role="page"` element in a separate page, which is loaded into the DOM via jQuery Mobile's paging system. But according to jQuery documentation, the `on` function should take care of that now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.on()` syntax that uses delegation (*that is that an element DOM hierarchy handles the events that occurs on its descendants*) is different than the one you used.. (*see http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events*)

```
$('container-of-#pageName').on('pagebeforecreate','#pageName', function() {
  // Compile the page using Handlebars
});
```

Of course you need to change `container-of-#pageName` to a selector that is a container of the `#pageName`.

---

If you can't do that then you could use the `body` and that would mimic completely the `.live()` (*but that is not suggested*)

```
$('body').on('pagebeforecreate','#pageName', function() {
  // Compile the page using Handlebars
});
```

Comment: What about using $(document) as the selector? That seems to work, but is it advisable?

Comment: it is the same a `body`.. The idea is you want to get as close to the `#pageName` as possible as to avoid long bubbling

Comment: Okay, I see. I'm not sure it's avoidable with the way jQuery Mobile handles paging, but I think pages are automatically removed from the DOM when you navigate away from them, so I don't think there will be excessive bubbling. Thanks!

Comment: I've confirmed that `document` works as the initial selector, but `body` doesn't. This is likely related to the way jQuery Mobile handles paging, but I'm not sure what the specifics are...

Comment: Yes indeed.. i did not pay attention to the actual event you were trying to catch.. `pagebeforecreate` is triggered directly on the `document` (*by the framework*). My description was meant for user generated events through interaction with the page.

Comment: Just to be clear, that event is triggered on the page and delegated to the document. It doesn't work from body because the body doesn't exist yet.

Comment: @KevinB, thanks for the heads-up.. it makes sense after seeing the comment in your own answer..

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me a couple of times and it was related to my element being dynamically generated after the javascript is executed.

Try this:

```
$('body').on('pagebeforecreate', '#pageName', function() {
    // Compile the page using Handlebars
});
```

You will want to use a parent element that is better than `body` but choose one that will not change.

Comment: in the case of jQuery mobile, the best for pagebeforecreate would be body due to the fact that the page is a direct child of the body, fyi.

Comment: @KevinB: Actually, I just tried using `body` and it didn't work – `document` seems to work fine. Not sure why...

Comment: Most likely it's because your script is in the <head>

Comment: @KevinB, good catch.. if the code is not wrapped in `$(document).ready()` and is called before the `body` tag, it would not bind to the body..